Converting a ring without unity to a ring with unity by products
Suppose $R(\oplus,\odot)$ is a ring without unity. If $\mathbb{Z}(+,.)$ is the usual ring of integers, and if we define the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times R$ with the ring operations $++$ and $\times$ as
$$(m,a)++(n,b)=(m+n,a\oplus b)$$
$$(m,a)\times(n,b)=(m.n,m\odot b\oplus n\odot a\oplus a\odot b)$$
where $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a,b\in R$.
Then, is the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times R$ with the operations described a ring with unity?
Though it is easy to see that it is a ring, but I am having a hard time in finding the unity element. The non-commutativity of the $\odot$ operation makes it look difficult. Any hints?

What do $m\odot b$ mean when $m\in \Bbb Z$ and $b\in R$? Is it just $b\oplus b\oplus\cdots\oplus b$ with $m$ copies of $b$?

@Arthur It is not upright mentioned as such. Does that assumption make it any simpler?

Try $(1,0)$ :-) This construction is straight out of textbook(s), and thus is also likely covered in earlier threads on this site. At least Jacobson describes it (and I don't much care for the rest of them, but probably many/most of them have it, too).

@JyrkiLahtonen I also lean towards that, but should we beforehand declare $1\odot a=a$?

If $R$ had a multiplicative neutral element $1$, and we equated an integer $m$ with the sum of $m$ copies of $1$ (ditto with $ma$), then, by the distributive laws
$$(m+a)(n+b)=mn+am+na+ab,$$ which is a big hint as to the origin of this recipe!

The only interpretation of $m\odot a$ that makes sense here is to think of it as the sum of $m$ copies of $a$, using the existing addition in $R$. Once you get to modules (if not sooner), you learn this operation satisfies all the natural "rules".
